# How to predict date of next visit in ML.NET?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

based on date of hotel guests visits, how can I predict next visit for one guest?

What solution should I use from this tutorials?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/

Data I have for one guest:

```
year;date;time
2000;31.12;12:11
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best fit for your scenario would probably be to use Regression. You can easily adapt the price prediction example to fit your data and what you want to predict.

It's this tutorial on the docs you linked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/predict-prices

Comment: In fact I have only one property in my base model and prediction model, and it is DateTime property. How to convert DateTime property into acceptable form? And how to get DateTime from prediciton?

Comment: You can convert it to a string and then have the stringed version transformed as the Label. The prediction model should then output it as a string (you can then parse it back into datetime) in the PredictedLabel column.

Comment: If each column will be string, or int (years,days,month), how can I be sure that ML will predict a valid date? Not something like this '2020-111-47'

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this as I've not personally needed to use date for anything but I'm assuming the format of the input data is somehow taken into account. When googling I found a couple of questions that handle datetime this https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3186 and this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311494/best-practice-for-encoding-datetime-in-machine-learning. I hope those help.